# Too little data to stratify

Tags: r, caret

I get this warning message after attempting to split my data using the `caret` package.

```
Warning message:
Too little data to stratify. Unstratified resampling will be used.
```

Even though I normalized my data, I keep getting the same warning.
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: The message has nothing to do with the distribution of your variables, but their size.

Comment: I did not face this warning with small data points, do you mean that if I have more data points, I will see this warning?